# ReferenceError StringBuilder is not defined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, stringbuilder

I have a javascript function which uses string builder function.it is working (95%) all the major browsers like IE8+ , chrome , firefox etc. I tested it and it is working fine, but sometimes I'am getting error like "stringbuilder is not defined". It is coming for some customers not all and I can't find which browser and version,so i wanted to know if stringbuilder functionality works in all browsers? Is there any version limitation ? I searched for this error , but did not got any answer. you guys faced any similar issue ? please suggest some link or way to solve this. below is my code.

```
  function GetXmlString() {
        try {
           var sbMain = new StringBuilder();
            sbMain.append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16' ?>");
            sbMain.append("<Application");
            sbMain.append("</Application>");
     }
        catch (e) {
            strXml = "";
            //alert("Error in GetXmlString " + e.name + "\n" + e.message);
            var error = "Error in GetXmlString " + e.name + "\n" + e.message
            $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                url: "AL_GetAjaxValue.aspx",
                data: { type: "LogError", Error: "" + error + "" },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(msg) {

                },
                error: function() {
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

i found the StringBuilder declation. is there any problem with this declaration? please verify this code.

```
function StringBuilder(value) {
        this.strings = new Array("");
        this.append(value);
    }
    StringBuilder.prototype.append = function(value) {
        if (value) {
            this.strings.push(value);
        }
    }
    StringBuilder.prototype.clear = function() {
        this.strings.length = 1;
    }
    StringBuilder.prototype.toString = function() {
        return this.strings.join("");
    }
```

Comment: Isn't `StringBuilder` supposed to be C# code?

Comment: @IonicăBizău **[I think Yes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12375/JavaScript-StringBuilder)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yeah, then it needs to be defined on the client. :)

Comment: True that.. but OP is saying _sometimes he is getting error_ then he must have included it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting that you would get the error sometimes and not others. How is it you are falling into this method? StringBuilder is not native to JavaScript but is a C# class.

If you find out that you need to define StringBuilder for javascript you can do so like this:

```
//StringBuilder class
function StringBuilder(value){
    this.strings = new Array('');
    this.append(value);
}

// Appends the given value to the end of this instance.
StringBuilder.prototype.append = function (value){
    if (value){
        this.strings.push(value);
    }
}

StringBuilder.prototype.appendLine = function(value){
    if(value){
        this.strings.push(value);
        this.strings.push("\n");
    }
}

// Clears the string buffer
StringBuilder.prototype.clear = function (){
    this.strings.length = 1;
}

// Converts this instance to a String.
StringBuilder.prototype.toString = function (){
    return this.strings.join('');
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i updated the code. can you have a look in to it. help appreciated.

Comment: So for one you are calling .append when the function is defined as Append so there is a problem there.

Comment: sorry , Thanks for the point. i updated the code.But it is working fine for 90%  and failing 10%. is that will be the problem ?

Comment: Dunno depends on when you create add the StringBuilder class to the prototype? Maybe sometimes it's in scope and sometimes it's not depending how how your javascript is setup.

Comment: the code which i updated is same as your code. i declare two StringBuilder object and appending first to second. is that make any difference ? bMain.append(sb.toString().replace(/%3C/g, "&lt").replace(/%3E/g, "&gt"));

Comment: What do you mean by 2. Are you trying to add both mine and your StringBuilder to the prototype? Cuz that is wrong. I am not really sure what you are asking anymore.

Comment: i am not going to merge your code and mine. i said , we are using same StringBuilder class. so i don't think so , that makes the error . i posted a line of code in above comment which is bMain.append(sb.toString().replace(/%3C/g, "&lt").replace(/%3E/g, "&gt"));. i am using two StringBuilder object (sb,bMain) in same javascript fuction and appending like this. so i am asking to you , is this line of code makes any bug ? i hope you get my point .